# Schema two-to-many relation (e.g. Child with Mother and Father)

Tags: sqlalchemy, relational-database, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to design a schema for representing a family with Parents and Children in SQLAlchemy. A parent can be related to many children, and each child has exactly two parents, father and mother. I can do something similar by using a many-to-many relationship.

```
family_table = db.Table('family', db.metadata,
    db.Column('parent_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('parent.id')),
    db.Column('child_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('child.id'))
    )

class Parent(db.Model):
    id = db.Column( db.Integer, primary_key = True )
    children = db.relationship( 'Child', secondary = family_table, backref = 'parents' )

class Child(db.Model):
    id = db.Column( db.Integer, primary_key = True )
```

However, since this allows for a child to have more than two parents, it is not satisfactory. Instead I have tried to manually specify the one-way relations from child to father and mother:

```
class Child(db.Model):
    id = db.Column( db.Integer, primary_key = True )
    father_id = db.Column( db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('parent.id'))
    father = db.relationship( 'Parent', foreign_keys = father_id )
    mother_id = db.Column( db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('parent.id'))
    mother = db.relationship( 'Parent', foreign_keys = mother_id )
```

My question: How do I define the relation going from parent to child (e.g. a children column in Parent table)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Just an advice: since you separate 'mother' and 'father' from 'parent', I think you'd better avoid a Many-to-Many relationship. Instead, a One-to-Many relationship seems better. And the classes should be like this:

```
class Mother(db.Model):
    id = ...
    children = db.relationship('Child', backref='mother', lazy='dynamic')
    ...
class Father(db.Model):
    id = ...
    children = db.relationship('Child', backref='father', lazy='dynamic')
    ...
class Child(db.Model):
    ...
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    father_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('father.id'))
    mother_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('mother.id'))
    ...
```

Comment: @onkel That's good and if you can click the 'support' that will be great! ;)